# Could not localize iOS app bundle display name

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, info-plist, cfbundledisplayname

I have followed the answers to some SO question to localize my app's name.

InfoPlist.strings (Base):

```
CFBundleDisplayName = "Name In English";
CFBundleName = "Name In English";
```

InfoPlist.strings (Arabic (Saudi Arabia)):

```
CFBundleDisplayName = "Name In Arabic";
CFBundleName = "Name In Arabic";
```

I have also tried adding quotation marks around `CFBundleDisplayName` and `CFBundleName`

InfoPlist.strings file is located at the root directory of my app.next to `Info.plist` file, but after localized, it was moved to `Base.lproj` dir and `ar-SA.lproj` dir.

However, my app is not using the localized name under its icon in the iPhone's home screen.

Comment: Did you remove bundle display name itself from project settings? Syntax without quotes is correct

Comment: Do you mean from the `Info.plist` file?

Comment: yes I do. it shouldn't be there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did sample project for you:

https://github.com/jurajantas/localizationTest

Hope it helps.